# Inline functions in c++ - conditions

Tags: c++

Under What condition an inline function ceases to be an inline function and acts as any other function?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: You're correct. I've removed the misleading statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Myth:**
`inline` is just a suggestion which a compiler may or may not abide to. A good compiler will anyways do what needs to be done.

**The Truth:**
`inline` usually indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution at the point of call; however, **even if this `inline` substitution is omitted, the other rules(especially w.r.t *One Definition Rule*) for `inline` are followed.**

> **Under What condition an `inline` function ceases to be an `inline` function and acts as any other function?**

Given the quoted fact there is a deeper context to this question.

When you declare a function as `static inline` function, the function acts like any other `static` function and the keyword `inline` has no importance anymore, it becomes redundant.

The `static` keyword on the function forces the `inline` function to have an internal linkage.(*`inline` functions have external linkage*)
Each instance of such a function is treated as a separate function(*address of each function is different*) and each instance of these functions have their own copies of static local variables & string literals(*an `inline` function has only one copy of these* ).

Comment: `inline` is much more than just a suggestion. It has even more important effects when use _without_ `static`. When used without `static` the exceptions to the ODR which it enables have important effects; with `static` they become (almost) irrelevant.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: erm..Yes, So doesn't it effectively mean an `static` inline function behaves like a normal `static` function and will have a copy in each TU and hence an unique address in each TU and `inline` has no effect anymore.I think my answer just says that.I was answering the Q "*Under What condition an inline function ceases to be an inline function and acts as any other function?*" the condition is that if it is `static inline`. or is there something that I missed?

Comment: Perhaps you should add that clarification to your answer. Without that clarification your answer means something entirely different (at least as I read it).

Comment: If I understand you, you're saying that an `inline static` function acts like any normal **`static`** function, but that in general an `inline` function *doesn't* act like any normal function? If so, then yes, I agree. The fact that your second paragraph only applies to `static` functions wasn't at all obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's at the discretion of the compiler.

But some cases just can't be inlined, like:

- Recursive functions
- Functions whose address is referenced somewhere
- Virtual functions (there are some exceptions thought)

Comment: Note that tail-recursive functions *can* be inlined by some compilers, and even if you take the address of a function, other instances of that function might still be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the compiler optimization.

Different compilers have different rules to make the code more efficient. But if you declare a function as inline, the compiler tends to respect your decision as long as none of it's rules says different.

Remember that the compiler can change completely the execution path of a method. For example, consider the next situation:

```
int MyClass::getValue()
{
  return someVariable;
}
```

At compile time, there is little difference between declaring this kind of function as inline or not. Probably the compiler will make the attribute partially public and code:

```
myInstance->getValue()
```

as

```
myInstance->someVariable
```

So it's more an aesthetical decision in most cases.